# Count number of repeated multi-character strings in file in bash

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to search for consecutive, repeated instances of numbers in a file, with each number on a different line. It's easiest to show what I mean in an example.

For example, my input would be:

```
16
16
8
8
16
16
4
8
8
8
```

And my output would be:

```
16 2
8 2
16 2
4 1
8 3
```

This may appear to be a duplicate, but though I have found many solutions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979653/how-to-count-consecutive-repeated-character-in-string-in-bash) one) for finding the repetitions of a single character, none of them are able to search for multiple repeated characters.

Comment: Do you mean repeated _characters_ (e.g. `111`), repeated _strings_  (e.g. `123123`) or repeated lines? Will each line of your input only consist of a string of characters (including numbers) and no spaces? Do you just want repeated lines?

Comment: @terdon - it was a badly worded title - I meant to put repeated lines.
My question sort of changed as I was writing the post. I'll edit the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `uniq` to do this, though the standard format of its output is slightly different.

```
$ < in uniq -c
      2 16
      2 8
      2 16
      1 4
      3 8
```

Assuming `in` is a file that contains the input, you'll get what you see above.

Comment: which could be piped through `awk '{print $2,$1}'` for a quick'n'dirty way to get output in the order shown by the OP